# Should I use a UIButton or a simple UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating an iOS user interface with a lot of different UIImageViews that will trigger actions when tapped (once is enough).
I have the choice between using UIButtons with a custom view (the image) or just setting up a bunch of UIImageviews with an associated UITapGestureRecognizers.
In terms of functionality I get the same expected result (action triggered on tap). My question is more about performance: the app will (lazily) load around 300 of these touchable UIImageViews in a scroll view. 
In terms of memory allocation which technique would you suggest?

Thanks for any help and guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIButtons.  They were designed for this and have been extensively optimized by Apple for [touches].  If you might need more advanced functionality in the future, you might use a UIImageView subclass w/ UITouch events.  Good luck!

Comment: This.  I had to create my own custom button class to handle gradient changes and its a pain.  When you need to handle everything yourself, it gets very tedious and some solutions are not always obvious or simple.  I've spent more time then I care to on getting it to work and behave as it should.  There are a bunch of things you just don't think about having to handle that you now do have to handle.